# Valid a phone number using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to validate phone number such as `123-456-7891` by using JavaScript and here my code :

```js
<script>
function validphnum() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("phnum").value;
  var format = [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4};
  if (format.test(x))
      alert("Valid Phone Number");
  else
      alert("Invalid Phone Number");
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="form"> 
<label for="phnum">Enter Phone Number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): </label> 
<input type = "text" id = "phnum"> 
<button onclick="validphnum()" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is a terrible idea. Not every phone number looks like this, and not everyone writes their number with dashes. In particular, there may be people who DO NOT have a local number but only an international one (e.g. someone who's in the country just for a limited time and didn't get a local SIM card). So you absolutely need to accept international format (`+123456...`) and ideally just strip anything that's not a leading `+` or a digit. If you truly care about having a valid number, send an SMS (or call). But if e.g. a random online shop did that I'd just order elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of small changes to the `format` regex variable should fix this.

We need to add `/` before and after the expression to ensure it's recognized as a regular expression.

Also the boundary assertions `^` and `$` at either end to ensure the user can't enter characters before or after the phone number.

```js
function validphnum() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("phnum").value;
  var format = /^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
  if (format.test(x))
      alert("Valid Phone Number");
  else
      alert("Invalid Phone Number");
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="form"> 
        <label for="phnum">Enter Phone Number (XXX-XXX-XXXX): </label> 
        <input type = "text" id = "phnum"> 
        <button onclick="validphnum()" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses the regex in **Figure I**. In validation when change event is fired on `<form>` and the input event is fired on `<form>` as well. During submit event, the built-in validation also uses the regex by the `<input>`s `pattern` attribute:

```js
/^(\d{3}(\s|\-)|\(\d{3}\)\s)\d{3}(\-|\s)\d{4}$/mig
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Fl0o9l/1)</kbd>

```js
document.forms.main.addEventListener('input', hint);
document.forms.main.addEventListener('change', validate);

function hint(event) {
  const typedIn = event.target;
  const IO = this.elements;
  const inputs = [...IO.contact];
  const messages = [...IO.message];
  let idx = inputs.indexOf(typedIn);
  let msg = messages[idx];

  if (typedIn.name === 'contact') {
    if (typedIn.validity.valid) {
      msg.textContent = '';
      msg.classList.remove('error');
    }
  }
}

function validate(event) {
  const typedIn = event.target;
  const IO = this.elements;
  const inputs = [...IO.contact];
  const messages = [...IO.message];
  let idx = inputs.indexOf(typedIn);
  let msg = messages[idx];
  let txt = typedIn.value;

  const rgx = new RegExp(/^(\d{3}(\s|\-)|\(\d{3}\)\s)\d{3}(\-|\s)\d{4}$/, 'mig');

  if (typedIn.name === 'contact') {
    if (!rgx.test(txt)) {
      msg.textContent = '';
      msg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
      <pre>
      <mark>${typedIn.value}</mark> 
      is not a valid phone number.
      ex. (123) 456-7890
          123-456-7890
          123 456-7890
          123 456 7890</pre>`);
      msg.classList.add('error');
    } else {
      msg.textContent = '';
      msg.classList.remove('error');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 400 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
}

input {
  font-family: Consolas;
  width: 8em
}

input:valid {
  outline: 3px inset green;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

input:invalid {
  outline: 3px inset red;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
}

[name='message'] {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: max-content;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.error {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  transition: 0.75s;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>

  <label for='work'>Work:&ThickSpace;</label>
  <output name='message'></output>
  <input id='work' name='contact' type='tel' pattern="(\d{3}(\s|\-)|\(\d{3}\)\s)\d{3}(\-|\s)\d{4}" minlength='10' maxlength='14' size='12' optional>

  <label for='personal'>&ThickSpace;Personal:&ThickSpace;</label><output name='message'></output>
  <input id='personal' name='contact' type='tel' minlength='10' maxlength='14' size='12' required>&ThickSpace;

  <button>Done</button>

</form>
```